# Define Custom Attributes for Spark View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Is there any way (preferably without modifying the source) that you can define a custom attribute to apply to your spark elements?

For example, I'd like to define a "permission" attribute so that I can do something like:

```
<div permission="CanViewDivs">

</div>
```

which would then map to a specific bit of code that would determine if the current user can view divs and hide it if not.

I know about the `condition` attribute and the spark bindings, but these don't quite accomplish what I want.

Comment: I know this isn't answering your question, but if it were me, I'd put the permission as a bool on your ViewModel, then use `<div if="CanViewDivs">...</div>` that way the Controller is making the decision to show/hide, not your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No" I'm afraid. To do this, we'd have to have some kind of schema that we'd feed into the Special Node parser and compiler, and I just don't see that as tenable or pragmatic unless you can convince me otherwise :)

Happy to look at the use cases for this in more depth and decide if it's the kind of thing that can be added. But as Dave said in his comment, this kind of visual logic should come from the view models, or at least that's the way I build my projects. But then you're probably letting your users edit the templates themselves and you've got a rendering subsystem behind this I imagine which is why you're asking in the first place - i.e. you want to give more power to your users without having to recompile the software...

This sadly is something I don't think a view engine should be responsible for, but as I said, I'd be happy to chat about possible use cases...

You know how to get in touch...

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob. I'll have to think more about the use case and see if we're trying to solve the wrong problem. The use case I put up is much simplified and I have a feeling that this isn't the right way to go about solving this problem but haven't thought it through enough to actually express why.